# О теме «обреченной любви» в итоговом сочинении

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, литературоведение, анализ-текста, текст

Меня заинтересовала тема «обреченной любви» в том плане, как она понимается школьниками.  Можно ли, к примеру,  **любовь Татьяны  к Онегину считать «обреченной с самого начала»**  и найти  в ее ситуации что-то общее с Катериной из «Грозы»?

Конечно, с первого взгляда  трудно обнаружить  сходство, но такое сравнение позволило бы более точно определить, что именно делает это  чувство обреченным.

И возможна  ли такая  «изначальная обреченность»  любви  в современном мире с его  стертыми границами (как территориальными, так и нравственными)?

Собственно говоря, меня интересует **логика построения текста** и правильное употребление слов, а эта тема непосредственно относится **к русскому языку.**

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** Я прочитала в качестве примера одно из сочинений на тему трагичной любви, и его содержание  произвело на меня не лучшее впечатление **отсутствием логики в рассуждениях и набором красивых, но бессмысленных фраз**, например: "Любовь самозаконодательна и свободна, оттого и трагична. Эта трагичность порождается конфликтом господствующих в обществе нравственных требований и невозможности их выполнения в рамках любви (точнее было бы сказано, что именно нравственные требования накладывают на это прекрасное и безграничное по своей сути чувство ограничения).

Вот мне и показалось, что надо ставить **другие задачи:** не Олесю с Катериной сравнивать по известному шаблону, а что-нибудь менее популярное.

По вопросу [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462866/Какие-произведения-можно-привести-в-качестве-аргумента-к-сочинению-по-пьесе-Гро](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%93%D1%80%D0%BE)

Answer (score 2):

"Любовь самозаконодательна и свободна, оттого и трагична"- набор слов, я вообще не понимаю слова "самозаконодательна" - сам себе закон сочиняет?

А вот насчёт обречённости любви Катерины и Бориса можно поспорить, вернее, поддержать эту мысль, разобраться в душевной драме Катерины, выросшей в атмосфере любви и свободы в родительском доме и вдруг попавшей "тёмное царство" дома Кабанихи. Вышла замуж без любви, но пыталась полюбить мужа, а как его любить-то - безвольного пьяницу, неспособного постоять ни за себя, ни за жену? На безрыбье и рак рыба - полюбила Бориса Григорьевича, мечтала о счастье с ним, а  и он оказался слаб, немощен, связан заботой о приданом сестры. Разве возможно счастье вольной птицы Катерины и жалкой жертвы Бориса? А ведь она готова была ради него пойти даже против религиозных запретов - это уже подвиг во имя любви. Только никому этот подвиг не нужен. Невозможно её счастье в "тёмном царстве" лжи, насилия, мире самодуров и жертв.

Сравнение Катерины с Олесей тоже не считаю шаблоном, у них много общего: она тоже искренний человек с чистой душой, способный на настоящую любовь, готовый пойти на отчаянный поступок ради любимого (посещение храма). Однако возлюбленный больше думал о своём чувстве, о своей работе, о делах, а не о том, что ждёт Олесю во враждебном ей мире. Здесь трагедия не в том, что они не могли полюбить друга в этом мире, а в том, что возлюбленный не смог её защитить, как, собственно, и Борис. Любовь - это ещё и ответственность за любимого.

Просто сейчас перестали учить детей мыслить, анализировать эпизоды текста, они могут только назвать эпизоды - и всё, а высказать своё мнение - нет. Я вот наблюдаю, что они по программе ещё произведение не прошли - а уже сочинение по нему пишут. Это как? С Интернета, слова в предложениях меняют. Это трагично. Отучают детей читать.

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий к ответу

Спасибо, но меня интересовало, **можно ли сравнить ситуацию Татьяны и Катерины.** Конечно, судьбу Татьяны трагической не назовешь,  особых проблем в ее жизни не было. С другой стороны,   и счастливой любви не было тоже.  **Так можно ли считать, что ее любовь тоже была обречена изначально, как и любовь Катерины?** Вот не было ни лжи, ни насилия,  и темного царства тоже не было,  а обреченность была, такое возможно?  Может быть,  **Онегин для Татьяны был не лучше, чем Борис для Катерины?** Вы могли бы с этим согласиться или опровергнуть? Вот если задать такую нестандартную тему, то общими фразами  уже не ответишь, придется думать, подбирать свои слова, искать аргументы и доказывать их, то есть учиться самостоятельному логическому мышлению.  Причем такой самостоятельный поиск для детей всегда интереснее.

**И по поводу чтения.**  Мы живем в другом информационном пространстве, и **нашим детям непонятны книги, по которым пишутся сочинения.** Это надо признать как факт и постараться найти выход. Если они не хотят читать, то пусть пишут сами о том, что интересно им. Пусть изучают возможности языка в реальности. Эти книги в конце концов уйдут,  ведь нам тоже неинтересны сюжеты из  17-18 века, но вот **язык – это наша главная ценность, которую нужно хранить и развивать.**

Пусть пишут о чем хотят, о том, что их волнует. **Главное – поставить интересную задачу.** Ну хотя бы так: кто лучше опишет зимний день (соревноваться они любят).  Можно усложнить вопрос: свободный выбор стиля, исторической  эпохи и т.д.  Разные есть  возможности для тех, кто заинтересованно подходит к этому. **Методика обучения тоже должна меняться.**

Comment: Да зачем же менять методику, если такие задания в этой сплошь и рядом. Сейчас заданий по развитию речи очень много, посмотрите учебник, через 2-3 упражнения - буква Р, развитие речи, сочинение - и зимний день, и зимнее утро, и первый снег, и чего только нет. Только если человек не читает, он не обладает нужным запасом слов. Те, кто читает, всё понимают, всё им понятно, и как бы ни менялось информационное пространство - люди всё равно будут читать классику.Жаль, что теперь нет уроков внеклассного чтения и дети не знают В.Тендрякова, А.Алексина, В. Катаева, а тексты ЕГЭ и ОГЭ дают по их текстам.

Comment: По отношению к "Евгению Онегину" более корректна, по-моему, проблема безответной любви, а не обречённой. Любовь-то есть: "Я вас люблю, к чему лукавить..." И он полюбил, по-настоящему, но опоздал. Вместе им не быть - в этом трагедия. Я не вижу здесь изначальной обречённости любви, причина трагедии - разность характеров и образа жизни. У Катерины и Бориса причина глубже - Катерина любит, а он только говорит об этом, не видим мы его любви, он от неё отказался. Похожи произведения лишь тем, что в них  женский характер сильнее мужского.

Comment: Я думаю, что любовь Татьяны тоже была обреченной с самого начала. Ее душа жаждала любви, а кого  в деревне, в глуши,  можно полюбить  этой романтически настроенной  героине. И она выбирает первого попавшегося, который  хоть как-то отличается от прочих:  «Ты чуть вошел, я вмиг узнала,
Вся обомлела, запылала,  И в мыслях молвила: вот он!»  Она и сама понимает это: «Быть может, это все пустое, Обман неопытной души!» Именно обман неопытной души – встретить  того, кто был бы ей душевно близок, кто оценил бы ее по достоинству, было практически невозможно, это была бы редкая удача.

Comment: Таким образом, причина в обоих случаях одна и та же – это замкнутый мир, характерный для многих женщин того времени. Не с кем Татьяне было сравнить Онегина, не было  у нее выбора. А впоследствии  «полюбил» Онегин, скорее  всего, светскую женщину, которой восхищались многие, вот  и он обратил на нее внимание.